# Page will not scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm editing a wordpress theme and I want the main content area to be larger. But when I enlarge it beyond the limits of the screen it does not scroll. And I know the most common cause of this problem is position: fixed, but I only found two cases of this in the code and when disabling both it doesn't fix the issue.

The original code makes a div with the id of "content" have a scrollbar, but I made the div much larger and so I want the scrollbar to appear and be back in the default spot like most pages have it.

Resources: Here is the original page for reference. (You can just inspect the code from there since I haven't made any edits to it yet anyway.)

http://themes.themolitor.com/wpzoom/2011/04/first-blog-post-title/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be in http://themes.themolitor.com/wpzoom/wp-content/themes/wpzoom/style.css, where html and body are set to overflow:hidden. If the content extends past the end of the page, it will not scroll. You can change it to overflow:auto (auto adds a scroll bar when there's too much content to fit), or you can just get rid of the overflow property because auto is the default behavior.

```
overflow:scroll /* always show a scroll bar */
overflow:auto /* show a scroll bar when the content of a box is bigger than the box itself */
overflow:hidden /* never show a scroll bar */
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've just done what you've suggested and it made no difference.

Answer (score 1):

You page has been setup in such a way that, a javascript file is placing an inline style to the content, and giving a dynamic height depending on the screen size.

and the content id has a overflow auto, which gives a scroll bar when the content overflows outside the parent element.

So if you wan to have the scroll bar removed either do "overflow: hidden;" (this will hide the content which overflows unfortunately.

Or you will have to rearrange the whole page structure.

Comment: I can disable that portion of the javascript. But there is no simple solution?